# Powershell : Get-AzureADGroupMember get all memebers of nested groups

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I have an azure AD group that is composed of 3 other groups.

Previewing the group in Azure I can see two tabs, "direct" and "all members". Direct shows the three groups, and "all memebers" lists the groups **and** all the members of those groups.

I'm trying to get a list of all the members in this composed group, but when I use
`Get-AzureADGroupMember` it only gives me the "direct" version.

What method can I call instead?

[image: Image of tabs described]

Answer (score 1):

Agneum,

I made some changes on your function for it to returns devices and users. In addition, it removes repeated itens and accepts pipelined ObjectId.

```
function Get-AadGroupMembers{
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory,
               ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
[string]$ObjectID

)

# inicialização de variáveis
$output=@()

#verifica se o parâmetro informado é um objeto do tipo grupo do AAD
try {
    $object = Get-AzureADObjectByObjectId -ObjectId $objectid
}
catch {
    Write-Error "Objeto não pode ser avaliado. Verifique se é você está conectado ao Azure AD usando o comando Connect-AzureAD
    e se o parâmetro passado é um objeto do Azure AD"
    return
}

if ($object.ObjectType -ne "Group")
{
    Write-Error "Objeto não é do tipo Grupo"    
}

# obter todos os membros do grupo (usuários e subgrupos)
$members = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $ObjectID -all $true
 

# laço lê todos os membros. Se não forem grupos, adiciona à variável output. Se for grupo, executa a própria função no grupo
foreach ($member in $members)
{

    if ($member.ObjectType -ne 'Group')
    {
        $output += $member
    } 
    else
    {
        $output += get-AadGroupMembers $member.ObjectId
    }
}

# exclui linhas repetidas do resultado final
$output | Select-Object -Unique
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For the time being I've made my own function to tackle this problem, it takes an objectId as a paramter (must be a group) and then loops through the list recursively.

```
Function  Get-AzureADGroupMembers($groupId) {

   $output = @()

   $group = (Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $groupId -All $True| Select ObjectId).ObjectId           
   foreach($objectid in $group)
     {

        $aad_object =  Get-AzureADObjectByObjectId -ObjectId $objectid

        #Add to output if object is a user
        if ($aad_object.ObjectType -eq 'User')
        {
                   $output += New-Object PSObject -property @{ 
                    ObjectId = $aad_object.ObjectId
                 }
        }
          
        #Recursive call if the object is a group
        if ($aad_object.ObjectType -eq 'Group')
        {
                   $output += Get-AzureADGroupMembers -groupId $aad_object.ObjectId
        }
     }
     
    return $output
}
```

Comment: I'm still new to powershell but i'm not seeing where to input the ObjectId of the primary group